# Slider Revolution - No slides found, please add some slides

Tags: wordpress

I need some help I have a slider and for some reason, I receive the next error message:
No slides found, please add some slides
Please follow this link to edit the Slider:

In the WP-Admin Panel I have the next settings active as you can see Mobile is On

[image]

Also in the general settings, the Disable on Mobile option is not active and for some reason is still not working

[image]

Comment: check shortcode that mentions your slider ID. is it true?

Comment: yes, the shortcode is the correct one (the same with the tablet / desktop one that works) and I have also sliders on that shortcode...

Comment: I solved the issue by importing another slider from another project and that slider is visible on mobile. As far I see in the settings they have the same settings still don't understand why is not showing the slider on mobile but the imported one with the exactly same settings is visible

Comment: You may use a template witch requires specific add-ons. I am happy the problem has been solved.